# Error al extraer Kibana sobre Linux : No se pudo crear el archivo de enlace fijo

Tags: descarga, tar, kibana

Intenté descargar [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) 6.2.4 sobre [la pagina oficial](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana), que permite visualizar tus datos de Elasticsearch y navegar por la pila Eslastic. Pero cuando intento extraer el .tar archivo tengo este error mensaje :

> ```
> An error occurred while extracting files.
>
> Could not create the hard link file:///home/mike/kibana-6.2.4-linux-x86_64/node/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
> ```

Pueden aydarme ?

Comment: Lograste resolver el problema?

Comment: @RaulCacacho, no. Me dicen sobre elastic.co que tal vez esta un error de permision pero sería la primera vez que me piden que enrute para extraer un archivo .tar.gz. Nunca lo he hecho

Comment: prueba entonces con chmod -R 777 nombre de la carpeta para que tengas el contro total